# Logout out issue in staging environment for multiple users in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logout

We have a app which is deployed in staging and devror env. we have deployed with nginx and unicorn.

If user will be inactive for 30 min we have set log out after 30 min if there there is no activity.

Here we are getting logout issue frequently some time when multiple user uses the staging app.

If a user using app continuously, there should not be any logout issue. We mostly getting logout issue in staging because I think more user access staging app

Any help is appreciated.

What could be the reason .. how to debug

Comment: You will need to share relevant code, can you start by sharing the code that is creating the inactivity logout?

Comment: "Logout issue" does not tell us anything. What is happening? What is the "issue"?